# Android - Getting input from last activity to new activity with xml layout being shown

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-activity

In the main activity of my app, it has the user enter their Name and click on a Shift number and click on submit. When they click on submit, it brings them to a new page (activity) and that page shows their Name and shift number again. But underneath, I want it to show the Timer (the timer that is provided in xml) but I don't know how to make it show the content of the layout and the input(intent) at the same time on one activity.

Help? Is there a way to collaborate the two?

This is my second activity's .java file:
    package com.cyapps.downtimer;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WinderDTActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null){
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            String opName = extras.getString(MainActivity.OP_NAME);
            String rChoice = extras.getString(MainActivity.RADIO_CHOSEN);
            textView.setTextSize(15);
            textView.setText( "\n\tOperator Name: " + opName + "\n\t" + rChoice );
            setContentView(textView);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the second activity's XML:

```
    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What I want is to have the second page/activity show the XML layout, and show the input that I got from the previous page as well. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

In the second activity, instead of setContentView(textView) use setContentView() and provide the layout that contains all the views of your second activity:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.SECOND_ACTIVITY_LAYOUT);
```

And to show the values from the first activity, pass them via intents while starting new activity. You can learn about intents from this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

**EDIT:**
To push a data to a target activity using intents:

**in your first activity** use putExtra() to add new name/value pairs before you start intent:

```
i.putExtra("message", This is a string);
i.putExtra("age", 25);
```

**in your second activity** get the Bundle object passed in:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

check extras against null and retrieve the values:

```
if (extras != null) {
    String message = extras.getString("message");
    int a = extras.getInt("age");
}
```

Now you can set the text of your TextView with the values of message and a variables.

Comment: I've done that, but using the R.layout.second_Activty_layout thing just shows the layout I want it to show, but it doesn't show what I input from the last activity. With the intent, I had to push the intent into a textview, and show the content of textview.. Is there an easier way to show both? Or to mush them together?

Comment: Intents are the best way to show a simple content like Strings, integers or arrays in a target activity. Please check the edit to my answer. I gave you an example of how to pass a String and Integer to other activity via Intents.